# Where to ask questions about programming tools recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Questions like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703862/postgresql-compare-databases-tool-or-generating-migration-script-util

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923280/can-you-recommend-a-database-schema-migration-tool-that-is-not-tied-to-a-particu

are getting closed as being off topic or non-constructive or for other ridiculous reasons.
These questions are often well defined and looking for a tool that solves one specialized problem for which such a tool is difficult to find by search.

It always pisses me off (and I bet others too), because it is not "constructive" only in the Stack Overflow terminology because the community doesn't wanna deal with some questions leading to flames or possibilities of many tools fitting the description.

I can see the reasons why these question are not desired on SO, but I'd expect the Stack Exchange network to create a site focused on these questions as as far as I know, it's currently impossible to get these questions answered elsewhere than IRC/twitter/etc. which is ridiculous considering the SE network already exists and the only barrier is social, not technical or even sensible.

Comment: If you want a new site (or) have a proposal for that, you should visit [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), *where users come together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed, discussed, and the best go on to beta*.

Comment: A question might be on-topic if asked like `I am using a tool X and I have tried to do Y with it, but I am encountering the issue Z` as mentioned by @Konstantin D - Infragistics on [Is asking for programming tool recommendations on-topic on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169933/is-asking-for-programming-tool-recommendations-on-topic-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: By the way, we don't close as not constructive anymore. We close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @yaccz: You can participate in [this proposal for a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) We need good example questions and upvotes to get this site started.

Comment: @juergend I've proposed an example question.

Comment: @gparyani: Thank you. But I have no upvotes left on that proposal. :)

Comment: Strange your question gets downvoted - it's a very legit question and I 100% agree with the post. Really annoying about Stack

Comment: The closing about "opinion-based" - I mean, sorry, dont exaggerate. Also solutions via programming are kind off "opinion-based". If someone fixes code, there are hundreds of solutions, so a posted solution is also an opinion :D

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere. Question about programming tools are allowed on Stack Overflow, but questions on programming tool *recommendations* are off-topic and will get closed with this specific reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Super User also accepts questions related to software (in this case, programming tools, but not about programming itself), but questions that ask for recommendations would still be closed as off-topic with this specific reason:

> Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. [Here are a few suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/) on how to properly ask this type of question.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I've up voted it. That said, [please read this about comments asking for votes/accepts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts)