# Confusion regarding the FAQ and a question

Tags: support, stack-overflow

[How to install Github for Windows offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646205/how-to-install-github-for-windows-offline)

This question was closed for being off-topic. The message was

"Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ."

I have read the FAQ earlier and I read it again. FAQ states that SO can be used for questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers". Is Git not used or is there some misunderstanding about the FAQ?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Stack Overflow is about actually writing programs, not about installing them.  Some installation questions might be appropriate on sites like ServerFault or SuperUser; but not StackOverflow.  "Common Tools" is more intended to discuss how to program in those tools, not how to install them, as far as I understand.

Comment: Already commented on Doorknob's answer to clear the misunderstanding. New to stackexchange so didn't knew that the 102 websites were all meant to used together by the same group of programmers. Still thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's more that each stackexchange is supposed to be a database of useful answers to questions on a particular topic.  You need to know how to write C++ code, go to StackOverflow; you need to know how to hack Windows to do something, you go to SuperUser.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: The answers from the SE community team [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119250/where-is-the-line-between-programming-specific-tools-and-programming) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy) seem to contradict this answer.

Comment: @Troyen Following the links there seems to be some confusion.  [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112443/november-2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest-1/112448#112448) seems to think they belong to SO. Perhaps the FAQ needs clarity on this topic?

Comment: @Zel I agree there's a lot of confusion (and the second link even says the FAQ is too ambiguous).  I do remember SE mentioning the SO community is too trigger-happy about closing tool questions, and it was brought up on a couple of the podcasts too, but I'm having trouble finding the specific episodes where it was discussed (since it's a pain to search audio).

Comment: I think those links do not disagree with me.  A question about how to use VS to program more efficiently is probably on-topic.  A question about how to _install_ VS is not really, I wouldn't think.  I definitely agree that the FAQ could be more clear (either way).

Comment: @Joe How does a request for clarity in FAQ be made? It would help in reducing some confusion.

Comment: @Zel I just bountied the FAQ question, we'll see if someone can provide a more authoritative update.

Comment: @Troyen Place the link here. I'll love to hear thoughts about that.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy) is what you're referring to I think?

Comment: @Joe I was talking about the bounty question. Is this the one? An update. My question was opened by a moderator for not being off-topic.

Comment: @Joe I noticed the bounty just now. Thanks for the link. I am new so didn't know what a bounty looked like.

Answer (score 1):

That's like saying "How do I use Google more effectively" is on topic because programmers use Google, or "How do I make tasty coffee" is on topic because programmers drink coffee.

The question is off topic because it has nothing to do with actually programming, it is just about the installation. It would fit better on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Actually the question included the programming part in the sentence "If there is no such client then what can be done to extend the functionality of github for windows or some other client?" but I guess I wasn't clear enough. I should have mentioned that I might be interested in using some API to try to extend the functionality myself. Still I get your point. Thanks for clearing the confusion. I'll be more precise next time.