# Proper place to ask question about an IDE

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to ask a question about an IDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide)

What is the proper place to ask about the pros and cons of multiple IDE's on a specific point?

I'm not sure if this should go on SO, superuser or programmers.

Comment: Definitely _not_ Programmers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about IDEs are probably most appropriate for SO as per [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> `...`
>
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
>
> `...`

Be careful to make sure the question is objective and doesn't get into [shopping-list question](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html) territory.  A question like "*Does Foo IDE support Advanced Widget Frobbing?*" (assuming that info isn't available with a reasonable amount of research) is okay.  Questions like "*Which IDE has the best Advanced Widget Frobbing?*" or "*What are the pros and cons of Foo IDE's Advanced Widget Frobbing?*" are too subjective and will be quickly closed.

Open-ended pro/con list questions generally fall into the territory of [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) as they're generally too chatty and have no clearly "right" answer.

Comment: Just to check, but asking for a GUI pro vs con list for some IDE's in java isn't a 'shopping list' question, right?

Comment: I agree.  There are a lot of people flagging IDE questions as off topic.  Questions about the IDE are *on topic*, as they fall under "practical, answerable problems *unique to the programming profession*"; if you're coding in it, then it's on topic (assuming it meets other quality guidelines).

Comment: @azulflame It's not a shopping list, but it's a list question; *that* kind of question is "Not Constructive".

Comment: Open ended "Pros/Cons" type questions are typically not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810048/pros-and-cons-of-java-ides-for-gui-interface/), then no, it isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Here's why:

- It's asking for pros and cons.  Such questions (by definition) are asking for opinions. What I may consider to be a 'pro' another developer could consider to be a 'con' and vice versa.
- It's asking for "Popular IDEs".  Today that could be Eclipse. Tomorrow it could be something else. Such a question is always going to be out of touch with the times.
- The question doesn't address *what problem you are having*. Stack Overflow is for actionable questions, not for navel-gazing.  If Eclipse is crashing on you, *that's* an on-topic question.
- No definitive answer. When will this question be capable of having a green check-marked answer? By whose standards?  There is no canonical answer to this question.

These types of questions are better asked in a forum, or some other venue that prizes discussion above canonical answers.  Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange writ large) is *not* one of those places.