# Migration of Questions from SO to Unix

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

[What is the difference between grep -e and grep -E option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-e-and-grep-e-option) was recently migrated from Stack Overflow and I'm wondering why. The SO FAQ clearly states that `software tools commonly used by programmers` is a valid post for SO.

*Is there a point of clarification that should be added/addressed in the FAQ?*

As a footnote, it seems that the whole Stack Exchange network is just meta categorization and there's no real reason that this question could not exist on both sites.

Answer (score 5):

I cast the 5th close vote, and I admit it was a borderline call.  I didn't think the question should be closed or migrated by the community to SU (where it wouldn't have been quite as good a fit as on either SO or U&L), so I decided to move it to the place where I thought it had the best chance of staying permanently.  I *could* have just wiped the close votes, but there's no guarantee that it wouldn't have been closed later when no moderators were paying attention.

Comment: How do you wipe the close votes close/reopen ?

Comment: @iain I assume by casting the last close vote, and reopening the question immediately after it.

Comment: @Iain Yes, that's right.  Just close for any non-migratory reason and reopen.

Answer (score 4):

There's a significant bloc on SO that strives to make it purely programming problems.  People have even asked [if IDE questions are appropriate there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide).

That question could have stayed on SO along with the other two-thousand plus questions about grep.

That said, Unix.SE *is* a better fit.

While SO covers "Software tools commonly used by programmers", Unix.SE covers "Applications packaged in *nix distributions."  Questions about what grep options do are better suited to the latter stack.

I wouldn't have migrated it, but it's not an incorrect migration, and shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: The "problem" I've had with this is that it strips people of reputation. The poster had <200 rep on SO before the question was migrated and would be fairly close to that level *if* it would have stayed in SO. The magic 200 rep is important for users of SE. I would absolutely *hate* having to get up to 100 rep for each SE site I use just to be able to upvote good (but not perfect) answers.

Comment: @hafichuk Rep dilution is definitely a problem, but one that hasn't been given much weight by SE so far.  If you think ambiguous migrations are a problem, consider the generally policy of making all rules changes effective retroactively.  Question upvotes switched from +10 to +5 and suddenly people saw thousands of points wiped out.  I feel your pain, but the powers that be don't appear to.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the question on Unix & Linux, we wouldn't have given it a second thought if it had been asked there. But there's nothing wrong with this question on Stack Overflow either: `grep` is one of the commands in unix shell programming. Unix shell programming is on-topic on both Stack Overflow and Unix & Linux. That is what makes the question on-topic, not “software tools commonly used by programmers”, which is not the case: that bit means tools that are rarely used by non-programmers, not tools that programmers use often, otherwise all computer questions would be on-topic.

That specific question was apparently more from a user perspective than from a programmer perspective; if there had been a context with a script using `grep`, the question would probably not have had votes to migrate.

I would have left the question on SO, but U&L is a slightly better fit. There's no harm done anyway.