# Where should I ask about Flash Builder problems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have an issue with Flash Builder 4.7, but I can't think of a place to ask about it. Basically, the Clean function is not working as intended and is throwing errors

Stack Overflow is related, but my issue is not with programming in it, but rather the software itself

Programmers is also related, but my issue is not with development of the tool.

I don't think Software QA and Testing is related to my issue

I am unsure of the purpose of Super User.

Is there a designated community for software problems?

EDIT:

This popped up as related on the side, but I didn't see it when searching for related problems earlier

[Where to ask a question about an IDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/where-to-ask-a-question-about-an-ide?rq=1)

-Question

> So, should it go on Stackoverflow, Superuser or both?

-Answer

> An IDE is programming related by definition!
>   StackOverflow is filled with questions regarding Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.

I think I'll ask Stack Overflow and see how that pans

Comment: Try Stack Overflow  first, then a 3rd-party flash-specific forum if that doesn't pan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow is the place to ask your question.

> but if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers  
>   …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Then you are even more specific :

> Basically, the Clean function is not working as intended and is throwing errors

Just show some code, some research you've made before posting and explain the problem properly.